# git case sensitive troubles

Tags: git, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have never used git on Windows before and am faced with a case-sensitive filename problem.

### Scenario:

1. `git init` in empty folder
2. check that `.git\config` contain `ignorecase = true` line
3. create file `dir\file`
4. add it as `git add Dir\file` (note that file will be added, by with different name)
5. make commit: `git commit –m “Test”`
6. now try to access log history of `dir\file`:

   - `git log Dir\file` show 1 record as expected.
   - `git log dir\file` show nothing.

Also, if you will go to `dir`
And ask `git log file` it show nothing.
If you modify file and ask `git status` is show

`\#       modified:   ../Dir/file`

### Disclamer:

I know, there are a lot of related materials like
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=286#c10
and workarounds with renaming files. I have dozens of such cases.
I am looking for pure git solution, without physically touching the files.
Reason: these files are under another version control system (I created a git mirror)

Comment: I apologies for my English. You can help me improve it and make correction of this text here: http://lang-8.com/472424/journals/95562431417159957095429000373272709566/git-stackoverflow-question

Comment: Using a third-party service for corrections is unnecessary on SO as it is possible for users to edit questions. When you click on `edited x hours ago` you'll see a revision history and may learn from it.

Comment: Thank you, it's work perfect (I mean SO correction tool).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I suggest:

```
git mv Dir\file Dir\x-file
git mv Dir\x-file dir\file
```

In theory, you will end up with `dir\file` in both your repository and your working tree.

Comment: 'git mv' move real files, not just working tree refs. And there are no version of something like '--cached' for 'git rm'. So it's same as just 'mv'